# C# string concatenation issue

Tags: c#

I have an issue trying to concatenate a string. The code is given below:

```
var name = person.name; // Let's say the name is Alex.

var htmlBody = " your name is <strong> {name } </strong> ";
var htmlContent = $"{htmlBody}";
```

The output I get is:

> your name is **{name}**

I instead want to replace {name} with the string equivalent which is Alex. How can I get this done ?

Comment: You are missing a `$`: `var htmlBody = $" your.."`

Comment: Add a dollar sign in front of the literal string.

Comment: You can search for [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#:~:text=%20%24%20-%20string%20interpolation%20%28C%23%20reference%29%20,string%2C%20it%27s%20typically%20transformed%20into%20a...%20More%20)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the $ while assigning `htmlBody` not in `htmlContent` that is too late:

```cs
var name = person.name; // Let's say the name is Alex.

var htmlBody = $" your name is <strong> {name} </strong> ";
var htmlContent = htmlBody;
```